# Update context menu title after it already opened

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I write extension that:
- When right click on page, it sends message to background.
- Background checks storage, if an item exists in storage, then update the title of context menu to "Enable", if not exists, then "Disable".
- When I click on the context menu item, it will update the storage (send message to background and updated storage).

Everything works ok, but the title of context menu update slow. Its title cannot updated if it already opened.

Here is apart of content:

```
if(document.body!==null&&document.body!==undefined){
          clearInterval(_thread);
          document.body.addEventListener("contextmenu", function(){
            chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"updatecontextmenu":true, "url_host":location.hostname});
          });
      }
```

Here is a part of background:

```
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse){
        if(request.url_host!==null && request.url_host!==undefined && request.updatecontextmenu==true)
        checkWhitelist(hostname(request.url_host), function(ok){
            if(!ok){
              chrome.contextMenus.update("my-context-menu", {"title": "Exclude"});
            }else{
              chrome.contextMenus.update("my-context-menu", {"title": "Include"});
            }
        });
    });

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(function (e) {//update storage});
```

It also updates, but not right on the first time when context menu appears, just in next time (from second time).

Comment: "contextmenu" is fired too late, you need to intercept "mousedown" and "keydown".

Comment: Well, it (mousedown) works :) Thank you!